# gretty throws org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process command {} finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: gradle, gretty

I'm using following simple build.gradle project template:

> ```
> buildscript {
>   repositories {
>    maven {
>           url repoUrlPublic
>       }
>   }
>   dependencies {
>     classpath "org.gretty:gretty:3.0.2"
>   }
> }
>
> apply plugin: "org.gretty"
>
> apply plugin: 'war'
>
> description = "Servlet Template"
> group = "com.grp"
> version = "0.0.1"
> sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
> targetCompatibility = "1.8"
> repoUrlPublic = "http://..."
>
> //gradlew run
> ext {
>    javaMainClass = "com.pckg.TemplateJAR"
> }
>
> war {
>     baseName 'template'
> }
>
> gretty {
>     debugPort = 5005      // default
>     debugSuspend = true   // default
>
>     httpPort = 8585
>
>     servletContainer = 'jetty9.3'
> }
>
> repositories {
>       // project nexus server repository
>       maven {
>           url repoUrlPublic
>       }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
>   implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
>   implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3'
>   compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
> }
> ```

and with the version specified it produce following issue:

> gradlew appRunDebug Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en
>   Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005 10:45:40.594 [main]
>   DEBUG org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol - ServiceProtocol.send(61607,
>   init 61611) Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection timed out: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:244)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol$Writer.write(ServiceProtocol.groovy:76)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:179)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:118)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:53) Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en Exception in thread "Thread-65"
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value
>   1
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:396)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.javaexec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:129)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1105)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1100)
>           at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$6.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:100)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure5.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:208)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure5.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

When the gretty plugin version 3.0.1 is set, script works without issue. Any idea why the script is not back compatible?

Comment: I like to format stack trace like a code (to avoid wrapping), but auto validation reports my question contains lots of code without any description.

Comment: I am seeing similar behavior with 3.0.2: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol$Writer.write(ServiceProtocol.groovy:76)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol$Writer$write.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_beforeLaunch_closure2.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:71)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect 
at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol$Writer.write(ServiceProtocol.groovy:76) 
...
```

when running from IntelliJ IDEA.  Then I ran it from the 'Terminal' in IDEA, and it worked.  Then I ran it from IDEA again ... and it worked :-\

Not stopping to ask why ... I can only speculate that Gretty is trying to write some file, which it isn't allowed to, when it runs under IDEA (maybe files related to SSL certs), but once these files are written, it is able to read them just fine ... although an argument against this is the 'blocking' nature of the problem ... a 'security exception' would be more apt.

Comment: I have run into this problem again, and this 'remedy' doesn't work.  More info as event warrant.